# Deleting a URL in Google Search Console causes a warning that something important has been blocked

Tags: seo, google-search-console, robots.txt

I have removed a page on my website and put the URL as Disallow in robots.txt and I removed the URL in Google Search Console (Webmaster Tools).

But now Google is telling me that I removed a very important website.  It says it is blocked by robots.txt.

Here is a screenshot (but in German):
[image]

I am afraid this has a negative impact on my ranking. How should I handle this?

**Translation:**

1. Have important sites been removed? Details: A very important site
   has been removed (by request).
2. Are important sites being blocked by robots.txt? Details: A very important site is being blocked by robots.txt

Comment: Is this the same issue?  It is hard for me to tell because of the German.  [Google Search Console: Severe health issues, some important page is blocked by robots.txt](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90503/google-search-console-severe-health-issues-some-important-page-is-blocked-by-r)

Comment: I added the translation to the question. It is one of the problems (number 2). But in my case, I actually want the page removed and blocked because it's no longer available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google likes to be able to crawl the CSS and JavaScript files on your website. They want access to it because they want to know if you're cloaking any content, and also because sometimes, valuable on-page info lives in JavaScript modules. If you're blocking a URL on your site that Google deemed important (maybe it isn't, but try telling that to Google!) you'll see warnings like the ones you got.

The best way to remove it from the index, now that you've deleted it, is to 301 redirect it. Then, take it out of your Search Console and out of your robots.txt. Google will crawl it, find a 301 redirect, and eventually take it out of the index naturally.

Comment: Thanks, I considered that option. I was not sure it is best practice because that old page's content is pretty different from my current page's content.

Comment: Yes, ideally you would redirect it to a similar page. But if a similar page isn't available, it's still better to redirect it to a different page - even the home page - than to leave it in the index. There's no penalty for it, and it ensures that you'll have one less 404 on your hands.